# INSERT .. SELECT with some default values in MySQL with JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

Lets say I have a table `Person(id, fname, lname)` and it contains a record `(1, 'Michael', 'Bay')`. Now I wish to create another record in `Person` table with the same fname and lname but different id i.e. `(453456, 'Michael', 'Bay')`. This is the way I would do in plain SQL

```sql
INSERT INTO Person(id, fname, lname)
SELECT 453456, Person.fname, Person.lname
FROM Person
WHERE Person.id = 1;
```

How can this be done with JOOQ (ideally while retaining JOOQ's code generation and type safety features)?

I am aware that JOOQ provides ability to copy entire records from one table to same or another table with its `selectFrom` syntax

```java
jooq.insertInto(PERSON)
      .select(selectFrom(PERSON).where(PERSON.ID.eq(1)))
      .execute();
```

But in my case, there are only certain columns in the record that I need to copy while the rest of the values needed to be set explicitly

Another solution I could think of is the following

```java
jooq.insertInto(PERSON)
      .values(452452)
      .execute();

jooq.update(PERSON)
  .set(row(PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME),
       select(PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
      .from(PERSON)
      .where(PERSON.ID.eq(1)))
  .where(PERSON.ID.eq(452452))
  .execute();
```

But it doesn't feel right. I would be grateful if someone could provide any other solution/workaround for this problem.

Comment: Doesn't JOOQ provide a way to do native (plain) SQL https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-executor/

Comment: Hi Raymond. Yes, I am aware of that. I was looking for a solution that uses code generation and ensure type safety. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
jooq.insertInto(PERSON)
    .columns(PERSON.ID, PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
    .select(select(val(452452), PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
           .from(PERSON)
           .where(PERSON.ID.eq(1)))
    .execute();
```

As always, this is assuming the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: Cool!. I was totally unaware about the val function. Thanks Lukas!

Comment: @rkudva: Yet, you were using it all the time, behind the scenes (e.g. of `Field.eq(T)`) :-) Here's more info: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values

Comment: In my application, `java.util.UUID` is stored as `BINARY` data type in MySQL. The default JDBC data type for `BINARY` is byte[]. So I have a custom converter to translate between UUID and byte[]. In my original problem that I posted, if `Person.id` is of type `BINARY` and I have a constant `UUID` variable with me, how can I use it with `DSL.val` function? Right now as it is, it throws the following exception

`Data truncation: Data too long for column 'snapshot_id' at row 1;`

Is the issue possibly related to [this](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4556)

Comment: @rkudva: Can you please ask a new question?

Comment: I figured out the answer to my question


`UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();`

`jooq.insertInto(PERSON)
    .columns(PERSON.ID, PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
    .select(select(val(id, SQLDataType.BINARY.asConvertedDataType(new UuidBinaryConverter())), PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
           .from(PERSON)
           .where(PERSON.ID.eq(1)))
    .execute();`

Comment: @rkudva: Still, a new question would have been very useful, both for yourself (better formatting, style), and for all future visitors. You know, you can answer your own questions here on Stack Overflow to help a future visitor with your documented solution to a problem...

Comment: Lukas, I have created a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741895/using-custom-converter-for-jooqs-dsl-val/50741896#50741896) and posted my solution. Thanks!

Comment: @rkudva: Very cool, thank you very much. That's definitely going to help a few people in the future! :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! This saved my life! Just a note to any Kotlin users, if you encounter an error with using `val`, try import alias it: `import org.jooq.impl.DSL.\`val\` as DSLVal`

Comment: @HeyThere: You can always use the alias `DSL.value()`

Comment: @LukasEder Oh cool, that's even better :) Thanks again!