# Using custom converter for JOOQ's DSL.val()

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

In my application, a piece of content is identified using `java.util.UUID`. While storing information in the database, the corresponding MySQL data type that I am using is `BINARY(16)`. The default JDBC data type for `BINARY` is `byte[]`. So I have a custom `org.jooq.Converter` to translate between UUID and byte[].

I have a use-case in which I need to copy a record from a table into the same table but copy only certain columns and not all. In the original question I had posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50513519/9413958), The following was the solution

```java
public void copy(UUID source, UUID target) {
    jooq.insertInto(PERSON)
            .columns(PERSON.ID, PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
            .select(select(val(target), PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
                   .from(PERSON)
                   .where(PERSON.ID.eq(source)))
            .execute();
}
```

But executing this piece of code led to an exception

`Data truncation: Data too long for column 'id' at row 1`

I figured out that `DSL.val()` was not using the custom converter I had in place for converting UUID to byte[]. How can I force the DSL.val() function to use the custom converter?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Use `DSL.val(java.lang.Object value, DataType<T> type)` instead of just `DSL.val(java.lang.Object value)`

Following is the updated code snippet

```java
public void copy(UUID source, UUID target) {
    DataType<UUID> uuidType = SQLDataType.BINARY
                                .asConvertedDataType(new UuidBinaryConverter());
    jooq.insertInto(PERSON)
            .columns(PERSON.ID, PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
            .select(select(val(target, uuidType), PERSON.FNAME, PERSON.LNAME)
                   .from(PERSON)
                   .where(PERSON.ID.eq(source)))
            .execute();
}
```